# Add List<string> as new tuple to existing List<Tuple<double,double,string>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an existing list `List<Tuple<double,double,string>>` MyList and I generate another list `List<string>` GeneratedList using the values from the first list.

Both have the same number of items;

I would like to know if there's a way for me to generate a new list, combining these previous lists into a final list `List<Tuple<double,double,string,string>>` FinalList

```
var MyList= new List<Tuple<double, double, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create( 1,1, "cow" ),
    Tuple.Create( 5,2, "chickens" ),
    Tuple.Create( 1,3, "airplane" )
};

List<string> GeneratedList = new List<string>();
GeneratedList.Add("val1");
GeneratedList.Add("val2");
GeneratedList.Add("val3");
```

Expected final value:

```
var FinalList= new List<Tuple<double, double, string, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create( 1, 1,"cow", "val1" ),
    Tuple.Create( 5,2, "chickens", "val2" ),
    Tuple.Create( 1,3, "airplane", "val3" )
};
```

I've tried using a for but the lists are very heavy, and I was looking for a faster way.

Comment: You can use LINQ's `Zip` method, but it won't be any faster than proper `for` loop.

Comment: You can use `Enumerable.Zip` method: `var finalList = MyList.Zip(GeneratedList, (tuple, str) => Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3, str)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1) method:

```
var FinalList = MyList
     .Zip(GeneratedList, (tuple, s) => Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3, s))
     .ToList();
```

Note that:

> If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them

So you possibly you may need another behavior if number of elements in collections differs.

Answer (score 1):

If they have the same length you can do it with LINQ:

```
var MyList = new List<Tuple<double, double, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create( 1d, 1d, "cow" ),
    Tuple.Create( 5d, 2d, "chickens" ),
    Tuple.Create( 1d, 3d, "airplane" )
};

List<string> GeneratedList = new List<string>();
GeneratedList.Add("val1");
GeneratedList.Add("val2");
GeneratedList.Add("val3");

var FinalList = MyList
    .Select((item, index) => Tuple.Create(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3, GeneratedList[index]))
    .ToList();
```